# How to bind value to HTML editor on edit event of Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net GridView

Gridview has a textbox which is binded from database.

I want to edit a row and this edited text value should be in htmleditor(ajaxtoolkit control) which is placed outside the Gridview. That can be updated by htmleditor.

Comment: Post some code, this will enable you to learn as well, that where you were stuck.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, to prove that we're helping you to fix an issue, rather than write the code for you

Comment: Check this link out. It might give you some direction. http://forums.asp.net/t/1809710.aspx?Ajax+Html+editor+inside+ASP+Net+Gridview